# How to use parameters passed from client

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm doing a simple request from client, using jQuery and passing a parameter, which will be used to retrieve data associated with that particular id on my server (the data is in a JSON file).

Request client side:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("Doctor id: "+URL.id); //LOG THE ID OF THE DOCTOR FROM THE PAGE URL
    $.get( '/doctorID',{ id: URL.id }, function(data) {

        console.log(typeof data)
        JSON.parse(data).map(addElement); // ignore add element function  
        });    
});


var URL = function () {
// This function is anonymous, is executed immediately and 
// the return value is assigned to QueryString!
var query_string = {};
var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
var vars = query.split("&");
for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
  var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    // If first entry with this name
if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
  query_string[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
    // If second entry with this name
} else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
  var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]],decodeURIComponent(pair[1]) ];
  query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
    // If third or later entry with this name
} else {
  query_string[pair[0]].push(decodeURIComponent(pair[1]));
}
} 
return query_string;
}();
```

The URL function gets the id i need from the url, that will be something like `http://localhost:5000/pages/personaleGenerico.html?id=4`

I'm passing the id parameter in my get request, then server side I am using Node.js:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.get('/doctorID', function(req, res) {
  id = req.param.id;
  console.log(id);


});
```

I have tried both `req.param.id` and `req.body.id`, but i keep getting an undefined value.
How do I get the correct value i need? Am i missing something?

Comment: WHy not `$.get(` `/doctorID/${id}`)`

Comment: I'm following the instructions given by my university prof. Never heard of this solution, what's the difference with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `req.query.id`.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.get('/doctorID', function(req, res) {
  id = req.query.id;
  console.log(id);
});
```

Change the GET method to:

```
$.get( `/doctorID?id=${URL.id}`, function(data) { //...
```

Comment: Works properly now! Why am i not able to use the req.param.id? From what i've learnt should retrieve the parameters i've passed through my client, am i wrong?

Comment: @mattia then you would need `app.get("/doctorID/:id", ..)` and then you can visit `yourserver/doctorID/12`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are targeting query but using param. in order to change your code to use param you will have to change the following code

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.get('/doctorID', function(req, res) {
  id = req.param.id;
  console.log(id);
});
```

In order to use `req.param.id`

your `app.get('/doctorID)` has to be `app.get('/doctorID/:id')`

your target would then be `'/doctorId/' + Url.id`

[param documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params)

[query documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query)